# A reverse function with Monoid type class in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, reverse, monoids

I try to write a list-corresponding *reverse* function under `Monoid` typeclass like this:

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
reverse ls = foldl ( \b a -> a:b ) [] ls
```

and my attempt is like this:

```
reverse :: (Foldable t, Applicative t, Monoid (t a)) => t a -> t a
reverse ls = foldl (\l r -> r `mappend` l ) mempty ls
```

But I received error message from console:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type a ~ t a
```

I feel like I was missing something, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you need `pure r`

Comment: Think about what the types of `r` and `l` are in your definition